# Exceljs data validation not assigned correctly

Tags: node.js, exceljs

So I'm trying to add data validations to a range of rows in a particular column with the code -

```
const questionTypeOptions = 'AA2:AJ2';
this.addDataValidation(sheet, questionTypeOptions, 'C3:C9999');
addDataValidation(sheet: Worksheet, options: string, cellRange: string){
    (sheet as any).dataValidations.add(cellRange, {
      type: 'list',
      allowBlank: false,
      showErrorMessage: true,
      formulae: [`${options}`],
      error: 'Please select any value from dropdown',
    });
  }
```

So I want to create a dropdown in excel by taking the values in that cell range.
Now it should be assigning data validation of each cell from C3 to C9999 as range from AA2:AJ2.
So this works fine from the 3rd cell (C3) i get the desired dropdown.
But for 4th cell (C4) it assigns AA3:AJ3, then for 5th AA4:AJ4.

Couldn't find anything online related to this.

[The cell is from row 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psqpa.jpg)
[The cell selected is from row 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqkR8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use absolute reference:

```
const questionTypeOptions = '$AA$2:$AJ$2';
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. But now I'm thinking how it went on doing that without absolute reference, any idea?

Comment: @lakshyabaghel not sure what you mean. relative reference changes when copied, that's why the row was 'increasing', so it's really a matter of excel